# Error in Pyalgotrade in summary and graph

Tags: pyalgotrade

The program is running without error but the results are getting wrong. The graph and the summary results are different. Please check this. While creating Take Profit order and stoploss orders with the exit market signal, i am getting error.Please check the attached file

The error are in running takeprofit,stoploss and exitmarkets orders at the same time.